# Error 0xc000007b When trying to inject a DLL with detours

Tags: windows, code-injection, 32-bit, detours

I'm trying to inject a DLL to a new process using the latests 32 bit Detours library.

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/

It worked for me in the past but after a change in the DLL, it stopped working for all processes. When I resume the process I get a message box saying

> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application.

I've recreated this with a plain and empty DLL injected that has no dependencies other than kernel32.dll. With other executables it works perfectly.

Any idea why this can happen?

Answer (score 4):

It turned out that the problem was the the DLL I was injecting using Detours did have any exports. Once I added a dummy export, everything worked perfectly.

Comment: Erm, wait, so this worked on a lot of processes anyway except one?  This answer can of course not be correct.  Exception 0xc000007b is almost always a process bitness problem.  Like trying to inject a 32-bit DLL into a 64-bit process.

Comment: @HansPassant After some checking it turned out it actually didn't work on any process :) I've edited the question accordingly. 0xc000007b is a general loader error with the most likely cause being bitness. My guess is that if the injected DLL doesn't see any exports it messes up something in the new process and that causes trouble for the loader.

Comment: Very useful answer, as this was exactly what I ran into, after checking all manner of other things

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the documentation looked like at the time you encountered this but based on a dummy export apparently working around the problem and the current documentation, you probably missed some requirements stated in [Detouring 32-bit and 64-bit Processes](https://github.com/microsoft/Detours/wiki/OverviewHelpers). Unfortunately it says to do things without explaining how the pieces fit together.

Detours expects your helper DLL to export `DetourFinishHelperProcess` with ordinal 1. This isn't a function you define yourself. It will get compiled into your DLL as a result of calling `DetourIsHelperProcess` in your `DllMain` function as shown in the [Using Detours](https://github.com/microsoft/Detours/wiki/Using-Detours) sample.